# Query string for Global Filter in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, global-filter

I have a category dropdown filter on my website navbar that affects all pages. I do not want to create a separate View for it.

When the filter is used I want `?filter=category+selected` added in front of my query string.

**For example**, my query string should be `https://website.com/controller_name/action_name?filter=category+selected`

Is there a way to achieve this? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In your view, use javascript to get selected option value (put it inside a script tag):

```
function filterQuery() {
    let selectedCategory = document.getElementById("dropdownId").value;
    
    let url = "/ControllerName/ActionName?filter=" + encodeURIComponent(selectedCategory);
    
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

The dropdown will have an onchange event which will trigger above function:

```
<select id="dropdownId" onchange="filterQuery()">
    @foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
    {
        <option value="@category">@category</option>
    }
</select>
```

Controller action code:

```
public IActionResult ActionName(string filter)
{
    var dropdownDataModel = GetData();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
    {
        //Filter code
    }
    
    return View(dropdownDataModel);
}
```

You can also use fetch APIs to update options if you don't want the page to reload.